# Cover the container with image, but only if image is big enough (a mix of object-fit: cover and scale-down)

Tags: css, object-fit

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/killymxi/gjb10oqa/26/

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container-1">
      1 - cover
    </div>
    <div class="container-2">
      2 - scale-down
    </div>
    <div class="container-1">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/80/120"/>
    </div>
    <div class="container-2">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/80/120"/>
    </div>
    <div class="container-1">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/320/480"/>
    </div>
    <div class="container-2">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/320/480"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px;
  grid-template-rows: auto 200px 200px;
  gap: 2px;
}

.container-1 {
  background-color: #dfd;
  display: flex;
}

.container-2 {
  background-color: #ddf;
  display: flex;
}

.container-1 > img {
  object-fit: cover;
  flex: 1 1;
}

.container-2 > img {
  object-fit: scale-down;
  flex: 1 1;
}
```

[image: rendering of the example code]

- `object-fit: cover` (left column) causes ugly stretching of small images. Keeping them small works best for my purposes;
- `object-fit: scale-down` (right column), by definition, produces image at most equal to `object-fit: contain`, leaving empty areas even when image is big enough to cover the container.

Is there a way to achieve combined behavior? (Top right and bottom left images.)

Paraphrasing the definition of `scale-down`, I want to achieve the following:

> The content is sized as if `none` or **`cover`** were specified, whichever would result in a smaller concrete object size.

Note: I can't change the HTML layout (but I might be able to use two layers of containers - image inside tag inside tag) and image URLs are not static.

Update:
If CSS-only solution exists, I suspect it should involve recreating the `cover` fit in some way.
For now, I only see a partial solution, when image is known to always have aspect ratio on the same side relative to container (always taller or always wider).
Full solution seems to require a condition on content aspect ratio, which doesn't seem to be achievable today.
There is `fit-content`, but it can't participate in `calc()`, `max()`, etc., and no other ways to access natural size of images as in JS.
Best CSS-only attempt so far: https://jsfiddle.net/killymxi/gjb10oqa/30/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using JavaScript to inspect the size of the images and then apply `object-fit: cover` if they are large enough:

```js
function setSize(img) {
  img.style.objectFit = (img.naturalHeight > 200 && img.naturalWidth > 200)
    ? 'cover'
    : 'none';
}

document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(img => {
  if (img.complete) {
    setSize(img);
  } else {
    img.addEventListener('load', () => setSize(img));
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px;
  grid-template-rows: auto 200px 200px;
  gap: 2px;
}

.container-1 {
  background-color: #dfd;
  display: flex;
}

.container-2 {
  background-color: #ddf;
  display: flex;
}

:is(.container-1, .container-2) > img {
  flex: 1 1;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container-1">
      1 - cover
    </div>
    <div class="container-2">
      2 - scale-down
    </div>
    <div class="container-1">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/80/120"/>
    </div>
    <div class="container-2">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/80/120"/>
    </div>
    <div class="container-1">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/320/480"/>
    </div>
    <div class="container-2">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/320/480"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```